# Can you embed information into individual tokens?

Tags: tokens, erc-20

Say it is a gaming token. Could you for example embed and update the high score each time the token holder plays the game? The idea being the token would be worth more the higher the score.

Forget there use case. I'm just wondering about being able to include and continuously update individual tokens with specific information to show individual tokens to essentially have different value.

Comment: I am not able to answer this question right now. But I am wondering: Why don't you go the other way ? => Token always have the same value and give token to players when the achieve something.

Comment: I need the token to fail the Howey Test :) I believe I found a way, but before i present this to my attorneys, i just want to make sure it is technically feasible.

Comment: Do you need to follow a specific standard (ERCX ?) ? Because if your token should be tradeable, it ads a lot of complexity to the problem ^^

Comment: That's what I'm trying to understand (possible vs complexities). I'm looking at erc20

Answer (score 0):

As long as you inherit and conform to ERC20 contract, you can develop your token, essentially your contract in any way you want. That depends on your way of designing the contract here. If design okay, rest is only programming stuff...